# Deleting zero record file within .bat file not working

Tags: windows, batch-file, sqlcmd

I have a .bat file where I run a query and output the results to a file where the last part of the file name is based on the date & time the file is created.
Next, I look to see if the file created has zero records.  If it does, I delete the file and don't execute any additional statements in the .bat file.
If there are records, I don't delete the file and continue executing the remaining statements in the .bat file.
This is being done on a windows SQL server.

When I test my statements by adding a pause after each statement in my .bat file, the delete works.  What am I missing?

The code is as follows:

```
sqlcmd.exe /U admin /P 696946 /d p21 /S EPICORSQL1 /i \\gf-epicorsql1\p21shares\scripts\iConnect\iConnectQuery.sql /h-1 /W /o "\\gf-files1\shared\IT\Applications\P21Export\iConnect_Inv%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.txt" /s ","
FOR %%F IN (\\gf-files1\shared\IT\Applications\P21Export\iConnect_Inv*) DO (IF %%~zF equ 0 DEL %%F)
ftp -s:\\gf-epicorsql1\p21shares\scripts\iConnect\iConnectFTPScript.ftp > iConnectOutput.txt
move \\gf-files1\shared\IT\Applications\P21Export\iConnect_Inv* \\gf-epicorsql1\p21shares\Exports\Processed_iConnect
```

Comment: this code is complete mess, please edit your question, read how to ask good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The only reason I could see the `DEL` command failing is if the file name had a space or special character in it. Always a best practice to quote file names and paths.

Comment: What does `echo %time%` output?

Comment: double quote `del "%%~F"` and rather set separate variables to substitute your special characters so do something like `set mytime=%time =0` `set mytime=%mytime:,=%` and `set mytime=%mytime::=%`

Comment: @this.girish Please revisit the [code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) page and learn how we treat new site contributors.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard code was a mess no doubt, it's looking nice after Compo edited 10 hours ago.....moreover i said PLEASE edit your question.

Comment: @this.girish Breaking someone's spirit, specially new contributors, by telling them their code is a complete mess is not within the specs of the code of conduct. Again I suggest you read the page in the link I posted. Thank you.